# Why shallow copy does not affect on single element in list?

Tags: python, copy

I am using a shallow copy to copy one list element to other, the list contains dict and another list element when I tried shallow copy and checked by updating the value of dict and list element it is updating in the parent object also, but when I tried updating single element it is not updating to parent. Below is my code:

```
import copy 

li1 = [{"a": 20}, 2, [3,5], 4] 
print ("Before shallow copy1 ", li1)
li2 = copy.copy(li1) 
li2[2][1] = 7
li2[1] = "C"
li2[0].update({"a": 30})
li2[3] = 50
print ("Aftr shallow copy 1", li1)
print ("Aftr shallow copy 2", li2)

# Output:
# Before shallow copy1  [{'a': 20}, 2, [3, 5], 4]
# Aftr shallow copy 1 [{'a': 30}, 2, [3, 7], 4]
# Aftr shallow copy 2 [{'a': 30}, 'C', [3, 7], 50]
```

Here the value of dictionary and list (position: 0 and 2) element from the parent list is changed, but the value of single element (position: 1) is not changed.

Comment: What's the question? This is exactly the expected behaviour of a shallow copy. `li1` and `li2` are different - so replacing an element of one doesn't affect the other - but they contain references to the same elements so mutating one of those affects both lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dict element changed because you are updating the object.

your second element is unaffected to because you are *reassigning a new value*. What you are doing is storing a new pointer into your list. This changes what is stored in `li2` but not in `li1`.

Your third object is updated because the assignment to `li2[2][1]` does not change what list that `li2[2]` points to. Meaning here the pointer is not updated to point to a new location. So what you see in `li1` gets affected.

But `li2[3]` is a direct reassignment of that position in the list. So this means that `li1` is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

It's updating the parent, what is not updating is the already printed parent,
that's why the first element of the 2 copys are {'a': 30}

```
Aftr shallow copy 1 [{'a': 30}, 2, [3, 7], 4]
Aftr shallow copy 2 [{'a': 30}, 'C', [3, 7], 50]
```

Notice that is different when it's a assigned (not a pointer) value instead of the update method.

You can use instead the deepCopy method, its worth for most cases!